# how to get item in vba collection

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary, for-loop, collections

I'm new to VBA and I got a issue when trying to get item from collection.

I have a self defined class, A, and I have a collection `B=[A1,A2...]` by using

`B.add A`

Then I have a dictionary like `C={1:B1, 2:B2...}` by using

`C.add i, Bi`

now I want to get the `C(i)(j)`, I build code like following, but it keeps giving me error: object doesn't support this property or method.

```
dim levels as variant

levels = C.items

dim level as variant

dim newA as A

for i = 0 to levels.count -1

 level = levels(i)

 for j = 0 to level.count -1

  newA = level(j)

 next

next
```

The error happens when I try to assign the collection and class to variant, i.e. level = levels(i) and, newA = level(j)

I know I could use for each to build loop but I need to use the index, and the object it self(might need to modify the object inside the collection later), so wondering what's the best way to do this. Thanks!

Comment: "giving me error" is not a useful description of what actually happens when you run your code.  What is the error message, and on which line?   If `newA` is an object of your custom class, you're missing `Set` in the assignment.

Comment: Would be helpful to show a complete code which we can actually run to reproduce the error.  Also should be `for i = 0 to levels.count - 1`

Comment: Thanks for the sugguestion, please bear with me since it's my first time asking questions here. I edited the description a bit, and I think the real issue is when I try to assign object to another

Comment: As a general rule in VBA objects are different than variables.  When you assign a value to a variable you say 'result = calculation'.  When you assign a location to an object you always use use the syntax, 'Set variable = objectLocation'.  You did not use the "Set" syntax in your example.  The answer below avoids use of the assignment statement except at the very end, where the "Set" syntax is used.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which works for me.
Class `A` just has a single field `Public id As String`

```vb
Sub Tester()

    Dim C As Object, items, i As Long, objA As A
    
    Set C = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    
    'populate dictionary with a couple of collections of Class A instances
    C.Add 1, New Collection
    C(1).Add GetAInstance("Id001")
    C(1).Add GetAInstance("Id002")
    
    C.Add 2, New Collection
    C(2).Add GetAInstance("Id003")
    C(2).Add GetAInstance("Id004")
    C(2).Add GetAInstance("Id005")
    
    'looping...
    items = C.items
    For i = LBound(items) To UBound(items)
        For Each objA In items(i)
            Debug.Print objA.id
        Next objA
    Next i
    
    'direct access
    Debug.Print C(1)(1).id '> "Id001"
    Debug.Print C(2)(3).id '> "Id005"
    
    C(2)(3).id = "New id"
    Debug.Print C(2)(3).id '> "New id"

    Set objA = C(2)(3) 'Set is required for object-type variables
    Debug.Print objA.id '> "New id"

End Sub

'function to return an object of class A with supplied id
Function GetAInstance(idValue)
    Dim rv As New A
    rv.id = idValue
    Set GetAInstance = rv
End Function
```